# Iterate over Django model - segment by date

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I will do my best to explain this.  I have the following loop in my template:

```
{% for traffic in traffic %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ traffic.created | date:"Y" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.created | date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.sessions | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.new_users | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.created | date:"F" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.created | get_quarter }}</td>{# Custom Filter #}
    <td>{{ traffic.created | date:"l" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.reminder | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.campaigns | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.new_sales | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ traffic.sales_renewals | default_if_none:"" }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The above shows everything; which in this case is data that goes back to January 2014. What I now need to do is create a table that only shows data from the month of January, then one for February, March etc...  I can manually create these tables but having that much repetitive code in my template seems ridiculous.  Is there a way to create a loop that will create individual tables based on the month as the unique identifier? This way, I can create one temple table and spin out 12 months worth.  I have other data tables I need to create this same way, so finding a solution is critical to my sanity.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) but that will still destroy your page loading times as more traffic arrives (irony?)

What would be better would be to implement pagination into your view and then `order_by` whatever date it is you want, you could then start to think about search functionalities as required. To make this easier, django has a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) which has support for pagination built in to it so there isn't a lot of code to write

As a very quick example, this is pretty much the whole listview code you'd need

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = Traffic
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = 'foo.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.order_by('created')



{% for traffic in object_list %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced irony is the best word to describe the effect traffic has on the amount of time something takes so if someone has a better descriptor please let me know!

Comment: don't know why I didn't think of it this way...my brain could be a littler DRYer.  Thank you.